# Transiting Ukrainian border rail station without papers for Ukraine

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, trains, paperwork, ukraine

I'm going from Cierna nad Tisou (Slovakia) to Budapest (Hungary) via the Ukrainian dual-border station of Chop, but cannot enter Ukraine.

The train reaches Chop at 12:00, and my connecting train, for which I have a ticket Záhony-Budapest, leaves Chop at 14:10, while the first train back to Slovakia leaves at 16:55.

Would the Ukrainians, as a pragmatic gesture, agree to kick me out on my intended connecting train rather than sending me back to Slovakia for the sake of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sitting in the "sterile" waiting hall at Chop as we speak - there are immigration booths for those embarking/disembarking here, in addition to checks onboard trains (for others).
[image]
Upon arrival, I got off straight away and was ushered into the waiting hall. There, I presented my ID and train ticket to a female border officer, explaining I'm going to Hungary on a train leaving in 2 hours. I was asked to sit down, and after 30 minutes a male officer came with the documents as well as an entry refusal letter for me to sign. I was told (in *surzhyk*) that I could just relax here and board the train as soon as it arrives, and show the refusal letter in lieu of a ticket Chop-Záhony (though I bought hryvnias in Cierna nad Tisou expecting to have to buy a ticket in Chop, apparently I'm not expected to).

So in summary, though you're obviously not supposed to do this, in practice it's not a big deal to them. Not sure how much it has to do with me being a "low-risk" national and/or the fact that there's not a soul here apart from the officers (and there was only one person other than me on the train from Slovakia)

Comment: Well, I guess you now have to mention this trip under "have you ever been refused entry anywhere" on every visa form.

Comment: I would also be surprised if this entry refusal won't cause problems if you try to (legally) enter Ukraine in the future.

Comment: Agree with 2 comments, seems a silly thing to do and shows you have no respect for immigration rules.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo People reportedly overstay as a habit and casually pay the fine, then face zero problems on re-entry.

Comment: @TooTea I've been refused before (2015) by another country for allegedly not looking like me on the photo. Russia subsequently (2016) issued a tourist visa with zero fuss. Given my nationality I'll very rarely have to get a visa anyway.

Comment: @Crazydre Is that the official regulation or the result of an - eh - cash based indemnification system? I have currently no doubt that everything can be 'fixed' in the Ukraine with a proper payment, but they are at least trying some futile attempts on introducing law and order.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Good question; sadly don't know. But it shows that they're highly forgiving in practice towards Western tourists. Not that I committed a crime either way; not having the correct papers isn't a crime in and of itself, you just won't be let in.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Ukraine is super lax about border security, unless you're a Russian national

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica After visiting Ukraine a few months ago, I can't really confirm that. The locals were surprised that we had only spent 2.5 hours at the border trying to enter from Slovakia. There was also nothing 'super lax' about the police check I ran into when travelling within Ukraine, where my papers were tediously browsed searching for possible problems to increase the 'penalty' they had already invented for me doing something 'wrong'.

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica I've seen other high-risk nationalities get grilled as well.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Hardly super lax at major crossings, but more so than e.g. Belarus or Russia. About on a par with Georgia I'd say